# Wrong Redirect URI in Azure Active Directory API

Tags: javascript, azure-active-directory, azure-api-apps, microsoft-identity-platform

Running the Login with Azure LS1 API on localhost it works fine, but migrating the script on the server I receive back the following error:

AADSTS50011: The reply url specified in the request does not match the reply urls configured for the application:

I know the problem is on the App settings in the Azure portal where I should change the redirect URI with the server address instead of localhost:30662 but the problem borns here: since the app has to run on a internal server with an address like 192.168.1.xxx and the Azure portal requires an address with https:// certification if different from localhost, how can I manage this to not install a SSL certificate on the local server? Is there a way to insert a redirect URI without https://?

```
var msalConfig = {
    auth: {
        clientId: "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
        authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations"
        redirectURI: "http://192.168.1.xxx:30662"
    },
    cache: {
        cacheLocation: "localStorage",
        storeAuthStateInCookie: true
    }
};
```

AADSTS50011: The reply url specified in the request does not match the reply urls configured for the application:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the legacy experience, it is supported to use `http:// schemes`. In the new experience, the format for redirect URIs has changed. They are required to be associated with an app type (web or public). In addition, for security reasons, wildcards and http:// schemes are not supported (with the exception of http://localhost).

If you must use `http:// schemes`, you can go back to use App registrations(Legacy).

[image]